# Choose data in a dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm new in Python and trying to figure out how to work with dicts.

Given a json array:

```
{
    "accounts": [
        {
            "alias": "mc_beeline_rub",
            "fsAlias": "qb_mc_beeline",
            "title": "MC",
            "type": {
                "id": "MC",
                "title": "Счет мобильного кошелька"
            },
            "hasBalance": false,
            "balance": null,
            "currency": 643
        },
        {
            "alias": "qw_wallet_rub",
            "fsAlias": "qb_wallet",
            "title": "WALLET",
            "type": {
                "id": "WALLET",
                "title": "Visa QIWI Wallet"
            },
            "hasBalance": true,
            "balance": {
                "amount": 8.74,
                "currency": 643
            },
            "currency": 643
        },
        {
            "alias": "qw_wallet_usd",
            "fsAlias": "qb_wallet",
            "title": "WALLET",
            "type": {
                "id": "WALLET",
                "title": "Visa QIWI Wallet"
            },
            "hasBalance": true,
            "balance": {
                "amount": 0,
                "currency": 840
            },
            "currency": 840
        },
        {
            "alias": "qw_wallet_eur",
            "fsAlias": "qb_wallet",
            "title": "WALLET",
            "type": {
                "id": "WALLET",
                "title": "Visa QIWI Wallet"
            },
            "hasBalance": true,
            "balance": {
                "amount": 0.01,
                "currency": 978
            },
            "currency": 978
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to extract a value ['balance']['amount'] from a section where "alias": "qw_wallet_rub"
I'm not interested in rest of the data, only need to know what the 'amount' value is

I have no idea how to choose a particular sub-dict to work with. Search didn't give any valuable results for my case.

Hope you guys will help me with the case.
Thanks

Comment: If you are only interested by the alias and the amount, could a dict like that suit you ? : `{'mc_beeline_rub': Null, 'qw_wallet_rub': 8.74,…}`

Comment: Yes it will be acceptable, so I'll be able to extract the numeric value of the amount to use it later. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this it should work:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json

a = """your json string/file"""

b = json.loads(a)

for e in b["accounts"]:
  if e["alias"] == "qw_wallet_rub":
    print e["balance"]["amount"]
```

Comment: Thanks. It does exactly what I needed! Now I feel stupid :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee there's just one of them, but you can simply use a list comprehension:

```
>>> data = json.loads(your_json_string)
>>> print([d["balance"]["amount"] for d in data["accounts"] 
           if d["alias"] == "qw_wallet_rub"])
[8.74]
```